# How can I do this data structure in Firebase with Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like such a data structure:

[image]

I tried this:

```
  this.db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(`${this.id}`)
      .update({
        records: [
          {
            index: pointIndex,
            x: pointX,
            y: pointY
          },
        ],
      });
```

But this solution does not put `records[1], records[2]`, etc... in the database. Just generates an array and always updates its values.

[image]

How can I do the data structure shown in the first image to have `records[1], records[2]` etc ....?

Comment: This is because `record` has only one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `FieldValue.arrayUnion` to add your new data, example:

```
this.db
    .collection('users')
    .doc(`${this.id}`)
    .update({
      records: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
              {
                index: pointIndex,
                x: pointX,
                y: pointY
              }
             )
    });
```